# Where should I put libintl3.dll to make wget work

Tags: windows-7, wget

I've downloaded [`wget`](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm) binary for windows. I placed it in **System32** folder. When I try to run the command, an error pops up:

> The program can't start because **libintl3.dll** is missing from your computer. Try  reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

I've downloaded [libintl3.dll](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libintl.htm) and I've also placed it in System32. The error keeps poping up. After strungling for a while I've resigned and downloaded the instaler. That didn't help too, just made mess in my program files and documents.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That `wget` version is **1.11.4**, which is more than 5 years old. You can get a newer version here:
https://code.google.com/p/osspack32/downloads/detail?name=wget-1.14.exe

It is statically linked, which means you don't need external libraries in order to run it.

Answer (score 1):

There are more dlls required than just libintl3.dll.
You need to download the Dependencies as well as the Binaries zips from the [downloads page](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm) and extract them to the same folder.

Answer (score 0):

i had the problem with grep for windows, if you are running Windows 7; try to put the dll here :
C:\Windows\system

It worked for me.

Greetings.